# How to use AJAX to delete a post in a Sinatra Ruby app?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I'm trying to use AJAX to delete a post in a simple Ruby app on Sinatra.

This is my delete route, without any AJAX call yet:

```
delete '/posts/:id' do
  id = params[:id]
  post = Post.find(id)

  post.destroy
  redirect '/posts'

end
```

This is what I have in my JS file for deleting:

```
  $('.post-container').on('submit', '.delete-form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action'),

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'post',
          data: data
        })
        .success(function(response){
          $('.post-container').remove(response);
        }.bind(this))
        .fail(function(status, xhr, error){

        })
  })
```

This is my index.erb

```
<header>
  <h1>Hacker News</h1>
  <p>
    <a href="#posts">new</a>
    <a href="#">comments</a>
    <a href="#">popular</a>
    <a href="#">login</a>
  </p>
</header>


<div class='post-container'>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= erb :'_post' , locals: {post: post}%>
  <% end %>
</div>

<form id="posts" method="post" action="/posts">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">
  <input type="submit" value="submit new post">
</form>
```

And my partial that contains the delete form:

```
<article id="<%= post.id %>">
  <form method="post" action='/posts/<%= post.id %>/vote' class="inline">
    <button type="submit" name="submit_param" value="submit_value" class="fa fa-sort-desc vote-button upvote-button"></button>
  </form>
  <h2><a href='/posts/<%= post.id %>'><%= post.title %></a></h2>
  <p>
    <span class='points'><%= post.points %></span>
    <span class='username'><%= post.username %></span>
    <span class='timestamp'><%= post.time_since_creation %></span>
    <span class='comment-count'><%= post.comment_count %></span>
    <!-- <a class="delete" href='/posts/<%= post.id %>'></a> -->

    <form action='/posts/<%= post.id %>' method='post' class='delete-form'>
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
      <input type="submit" value="delete">
    </form>
  </p>
</article>
```

I know I have to call .xhr? in the route, but I'm unsure of where, and what to render. Also, how to get around the hidden input method for delete when using AJAX. I hope this is enough information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are sending HTTP POST request but Sinatra expects to get DELETE request. Two options:

Change your Jquery ajax request to:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'DELETE', // Change this
      data: data
    })
```

Or, if you want to keep the existing Javascript code, change your Sinatra application to:

```
post '/posts/:id' do  # Change delete to post
...
```

GET, POST, DELETE and PUT are standard Http requests and you can use either post or delete to get the result you want.